# Aligning DSM/DEM rastor data from cloudcompare into QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, cloudcompare

I am trying to import raster tif. files of downtown Portland,OR into QGIS. The data I used came from a NOAA tileindex file that used the corresponding CRS, NAD83(NSRS2007). I used cloudcompare to create the  DSM and DEM files, this is a screen-cap of the .las file properties prior to export:

[image: .las file properties in cloudcompare]

This is my export screen:

[image: exporting to raster .tif]

As you can see, I can somewhat successfully add the files into QGIS, the only problem being that it does not automatically align with basemaps or the other vector data I have from osm. It has an undefined coordinate system and the bottom left shows coords in the 500k values (which I am assuming is from the OG NOAA data itself.):

[image]

Compared to the data that does align in the same project, OSM, tileindex from NOAA, and Google satellite which is using corresponding CRS, EPSG:4326:

[image]

I am just wanting to get the tif. files to align properly so I can continue with my project.

Comment: Anything you export from CloudCompare won't carry coordinate system information, so in QGIS you'll need to assign, and if necessary re-project. QGIS easily handles data in different coordinate systems. Why did you run things through CC? You can get DEM/DSM data that can be directly imported into QGIS. Please post a link to your original data.

Comment: @Pointdump My original data,[https://noaa-nos-coastal-lidar-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/laz/geoid18/6377/index.html], under the tileindex link. The site is under maintenance fyi. The OG files are cloudpoint .las files I selected in GIS from the tile links. I used CC because it was most recent Lidar data I could find for my aoi ...and because I was piggybacking off a tutorial I found. The .las files upload just fine into QGIS, and my goal is to perform viewshed analyisis with the data I have, can I do that with the pointcloud data? or is there a way to rasterize that data in QGIS itself? Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to specify the DEM projection in the layer parameters in QGIS ? It seems that cloudcompare does not specify the projection.

Comment: @Atm , I have tried that - it does not  seem to resolve the issue.